# Generate random id in neosnippet html snippets

Tags: vim, code-snippets

I am using the neosnippet addon for code templates autocompletion, and I have a cutom snippet that goes like this (in `html.snip`):

```
snippet elemhide
    <p><input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('${1:hideID}')" value="Toggle show/hide"></p>
    <div id="$1">
    </div>
```

Since this could be used multiple times in one html file, I have to make sure that each `hideID` is unique. So I am wondering if it's possible to let vim to do the work for me, just generate a random alph-numeric ID of length 12 and put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neosnippet's documentation [says](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim/blob/master/doc/neosnippet.txt#L575):

```
Vim has a built-in expression evaluation. You can also use this feature inside
of snippets if you use back ticks like in the example below. Here the "%:t"
gets expanded to the name of the current active file and the current time gets
inserted by expanding the output of the strftime command.

    snippet     header
       File: ${1:`expand('%:t')`}
       ${2:Created at: `strftime("%B %d, %Y")`}
```

AFAIK, Vim doesn't come with a built-in way to generate random stuff but, in true UNIX spirit, we can [use external commands](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/) to do the work.

This snippet should do what you want:

```
snippet elemhide
   <p><input onclick="return toggleMe('${1:`system("date +%s | shasum | base64 | head -c 10 ; echo")`}')"></p>
   <div id="$1">
   </div>
```

---

I don't have neosnippet but the original Snipmate has this feature as well. This snippet:

```
snippet elemhide
    <p><input onclick="return toggleMe('${1:`system("date +%s | shasum | base64 | head -c 10 ; echo")`}')"></p>
    <div id="$1">
    </div>
```

gives me this block of HTML:

```
<p><input onclick="return toggleMe('ZjE5MjJkNT')"></p>
<div id="ZjE5MjJkNT">
</div>
```

YMMV.

Comment: In `date +%s | shasum | base64 | head -c 10 ; echo`, it seems `echo` is not needed. A very nice tip, though. Thanks!